# How to make "save file to" option when i click on download button in html or js

Tags: javascript, html

I have uploaded a file to my website and attach download link like this, `<a href="Path-to-file" download="">DOWNLOAD</a>`

Its there a way to save this into a specific location?

Comment: Rightclick the link... :O

Comment: Are you using any framework or core php?

Comment: Use reference from here
   [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3749231/download-file-using-javascript-jquery][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3749231/download-file-using-javascript-jquery

Answer (score 0):

there is implementation in git hub which supports text download , image download and many more.

below is the link

https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js